# how to export a large number of records from a table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am to export a table U_info in which has around 40000 records. when I am exporting it then I got only 3000 records. so How can Export all records of that table.

Comment: export in which format .sql, .xls ?

Comment: want to export in .sql file

Comment: you can try mysql dump as `mysqldump -u username -p dbname tablename > tablename.sql` this will be faster, and you can run this command on terminal

Comment: Can I run it in Mysql phpMyAdmin sql command line???

Comment: unfortunately no, you need to run it as standalone not on php myadmin.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the pagination for that. It seems you are using mysql which has limitations. I received the same error but for inserting more then 40k records at a time.

```
$cnt=0;
 $user=0    
 do
 {
    $user=0;
    $sql = "SELECT column FROM table LIMIT 999 offset ".$cnt;

    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $devices = array();     
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $devices[] = $row['push_id'];
    }
            $message = array("title" => $title, "images" => $images, "description" => $description);
    $resultOfGCM = send_notification($devices, $message);
    $user=mysql_num_rows($result);
    $cnt=$cnt+$user;

}while($user>=999);
```

Its my logic to insert same way you can export the table and insert it into other table.

Please find the above solution

Thanks
Nishant

Comment: To export the table run the following command from the command line:
`“mysqldump -p – –user=username dbname tableName > tableName.sql”`

This will export the tableName to the file tableName.sql.
[NOTE: there should be no space between the two dashes, but I have to write it that way so that it display properly].